# How can I hide the console window when freezing wxPython applications with cxFreeze?

Tags: python, wxpython, cx-freeze

I'm developing a Python application using wxPython and freezing it using cxFreeze. All seems to be going fine apart from this following bit:

When I run the executable created by cxFreeze, a blank console window pops up. I don't want to show it. Is there any way I could hide it?

It doesn't seem to be documented on the cxFreeze site and Googling didn't turn up much apart from some similar sorta problems with Py2Exe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This worked to some extent but it has issues. My program runs in both a console mode and a GUI mode. When run from the console with a `--console` argument it runs in a console mode. When I followed the procedure below, this doesn't work anymore and my program is only a GUI app then.

The following source code comes from a sample file in the `\Python\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4\setup.py`. Lesson of the day. Read the README.

```
# A simple setup script to create an executable using PyQt4. This also
# demonstrates the method for creating a Windows executable that does not have
# an associated console.
#
# PyQt4app.py is a very simple type of PyQt4 application
#
# Run the build process by running the command 'python setup.py build'
#
# If everything works well you should find a subdirectory in the build
# subdirectory that contains the files needed to run the application

import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
        name = "simple_PyQt4",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Sample cx_Freeze PyQt4 script",
        executables = [Executable("PyQt4app.py", base = base)])
```

Answer (score 22):

For Windows:

You have to use a line like this (use file folders and names as appropriate)

```
C:/Python/Scripts/cxfreeze C:/Python/Code/yourprogram.py --base-name=Win32GUI --target-dir C:/Python/Dist
```

By adding the `--base-name=Win32GUI` option, the console window will not appear.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Windows, you could rename your "main" script's extension (that launches the app) to .pyw

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I renamed it to PYW but it still popped up.

Comment: the script extension has no effect on the exe created via cxfreeze in (Windows 10, Python 3.11, cx_freeze 6.14.4)

Answer (score 3):

Option 1)  Use [gui2exe](http://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/) to muck with various options.

Option 2)  Modify your setup.py with 'base' parameter as such.

```
GUI2Exe_Target_1 = Executable(
    # what to build
    script = "rf_spi.py",
    initScript = None,
    base = 'Win32GUI',  # <-- add this
    targetDir = r"dist",
    targetName = "rf_spi.exe",
    compress = True,
    copyDependentFiles = False,
    appendScriptToExe = False,
    appendScriptToLibrary = False,
    icon = r"wireless.ico"
    )
```