# How to embed python console output to wxPython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

Is there a way I can embed the console window in to a wxPython form?

When I run my code, both the python console and wxPython Form open, but I would like to see the information on the App window somehow

Comment: something like `pycrust` ?

Comment: Are you wanting to redirect stdout from things like `print` functions?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I know it was abandoned years ago and comes with wxPython now, but the documentation is slim to none. Looking for something similar without all the extra

Comment: @MikeDriscoll Yes exactly, I would like what I print to console to show up on the wxPython App like in a text block or richtext, just a text window to output in general on the form without the console opening up with the app

Comment: I think it is better to have it outside, but for aesthetics - sure. What if your GUI has processes which already redirect the stdout? Wouldn't the answer not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to redirect after some searching

```
class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self,aWxTextCtrl):
        self.out = aWxTextCtrl

    def write(self,string):
        self.out.WriteText(string)
```

Then I just setup a TextCtrl from wxPython to redirect the output to

```
self.log = wx.TextCtrl(main_panel, -1, size=(200, 100), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)
redir = RedirectText(self.log)
sys.stdout = redir
```